# How to access image from folder in GeoJSON?

Tags: json, geojson, arcgis-js-api

I am programming a 3D globe using ArcGis API for Javascript and added a GeoJSON layer. The GeoJSON file holds information and images for several coordinates, which are displayed via pop-up windows.

When I use the image URL from my local server, as seen in the sample code below, the images are displayed as they should be and everything is working. However, I would like to display them by using a local path such as ".project/uploadfolder/imagename.jpg" instead. Is that possible and how can I achieve it? I can´t figure out how to make work, as the GeoJSON file seemingly does not support that format and the images are not showing up at all.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Mount Fuji",
            "category": "Volcanoes",
            "type": "......",
            "location": "......................",
            "imageUrl": "http://localhost/Projekt%C3%BCbung/upload/mount%20fuji-4733029_1280.jpg",
            "imageCaption": "Mount Fuji",
            "imageCopyright": "Image by ... under CC BY-SA2.5",
            "imageUrl_2": "http://localhost/Projekt%C3%BCbung/upload/fuji-960266_1920.jpg",
            "imageCaption_2": "Mount Fuji",
            "imageCopyright_2": "Image by .... under CC BY-SA2.5",
            "imageUrl_3": "http://localhost/Projekt%C3%BCbung/upload/mt-fuji-536284_1920.jpg",
            "imageCaption_3": "Mount Fuji",
            "imageCopyright_3": "Image by ... under CC BY-SA2.5",
            "relevantpublications": "Provide link to relevant publications",
            "source": "...."
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                138.73088836669922,
                35.36308599925639
            ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

From a GeoJSON point of view these image URLs are just string attributes. By configuring a popup template on the `GeoJSONLayer` you can make the actual picture appear.

This sample shows how to do that for various media elements:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/popup-multipleelements/

For your GeoJSON above something like the following should work:

```
var geoJSONLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({ /* ... */ });

var popupTemplate = {
  title: "Pictures of {NAME}",
  content: [
    type: "media", // MediaContentElement
    mediaInfos: [{
      title: "<b>{imageCaption}</b>",
      type: "image",
      caption: "{imageCaption}",
      value: {
        sourceURL: "{imageUrl_2}"
      }
    }]
  ]
};

geoJSONLayer.popupTemplate = popupTemplate;
```

You can find more samples in the popup templates online documentation:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html